# Creating personalized headings

Tags: header-footer

My homework consists of problems that each are 3+ pages long. Every time, I have to frantically scroll the output up and down in order to figure out which problem this is, where it ends, and where it starts since I only indicate the problem's title once by using the code`\subsection`). Is there any way I can create an automatic header on each page that will reflect which problem this is? So if this is Problem 6.40, the heading would read "Problem 6.40", and so on.

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The standard headings puts section heads on left pages and subsection on the right. If that isn't suitable you may want to edit your question to give more information about your input and desired output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\section{ZZZ}
\subsection{aa}
\rule{2pt}{5cm}\par\rule{2pt}{2cm}

\subsection{bb}
\rule{2pt}{3cm}\par\rule{2pt}{2cm}

\subsection{aa}
\rule{2pt}{5cm}\par\rule{2pt}{1cm}\par\rule{2pt}{1cm}\par\rule{2pt}{1cm}

\section{WWW}
\subsection{aa xy}
\rule{2pt}{5cm}\par\rule{2pt}{3cm}

\subsection{bb xx}
\rule{2pt}{5cm}\par\rule{2pt}{1cm}

\subsection{cc yy}
\rule{2pt}{2cm}\par\rule{2pt}{4cm}


\end{document}
```

---

By default section headings affect even page heads (or all heads in one sideed styles)
and subsections affect odd heads.

If you add

```
\def\subsectionmark#1{%
\markboth {\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>1 
\thesubsection\quad\fi#1}}}
```

which is the definition from `article` but using `\markboth` instead of `\markright`
then subsections will affect both pages.

If you only want subsections to affect the head and never the section then you could also add

```
\def\subsectionmark#1{}
```

so `\section` does not set any marks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Your solution seem right. Can we use one a one-sided document instead? So that the heading stays consistent for as long as needed. In particular, I want to make sure that each page has a heading identical to name indicated in \section*{} until I have a new \section*{}.

Comment: @Olga add something like     `\def\subsectionmark#1{\markboth {\ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>1 \thesubsection\quad\fi#1}}}` which is the standard definition but with `\markboth` instead of `\markright` then in 1 or 2 side the subsections should affect the page head on all pages, depending what you want you might also want `\def\subsectionmark#1{}` so sections dont affect the heading at all

Comment: Thank you! Can you please update your original post with the information from the most recent commentary?

Comment: @Olga answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is just not a complete answer but you can have a look at the fancyhdr package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr. Also the wikibook is useful: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customizing_with_fancyhdr . There you can create a header which can contain for example the section. Search for \thesection

Comment: You also can use the `\titleps`package, that comes with `titlesec`: the latter lets you customise chapters, sections, &c. The former lets you define `pagestyles` to customise headers and footers (load `titlesec with option `pagestyles`).